# MongoDB Not Responding on db.collection.createIndex()

Tags: mongodb, centos7

currently i'm using mongodb for my big data project. i have installed mongodb into Centos 7 server with 32GB RAM and connected to 12TB NFS. until now, this is my database statistic:

```
web-analyzer   43.933 GB
web-crawler   109.900 GB
web-crawler2  339.788 GB
```

the problem is, whenever i run the craeteIndex() on may collection, my mongodb always end up to not responding (i cannot execute db.collection.count() or 'show dbs / collections' command) so i terminate the job using CTRL + C. after that i cannot shutdown my mongodb using 'kill pid' or 'mongod --shutdown' command so i have to reboot my server. Anyone know the cause of this problem and how to solve this issue?

this is my 'top' command output for mongod service:

**before running the query:**

```
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 2896 mongod    20   0  0.965t  99220  70964 S   0.3  0.3   0:00.33 mongod
```

**after running createIndex()**

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 2896 mongod    20   0  0.965t 2.465g 2.411g S   2.7  7.9   0:26.03 mongod
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, building an index is a blocking operation which locks the database until completed. When you already have a lot of data in your collection, this can take a very long time. But you can build an index in background by using the `background:true` option.

```
db.collection.createIndex({ keyfield: 1, otherkeyfield: 1 }, { background: true });
```

It will take longer overall, but the database will keep responding while you do.

For more information about creating indexes, [please refer to the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#db.collection.createIndex).

Comment: great! thx for the answer.. i need to add the index to some column because the find() result is very slow :(

Comment: @SalmanElFarisi There are no *columns* in MongoDB, only documents and fields.

Comment: @SalmanElFarisi keep in mind that indexes can be used in sorting, and sometimes index is used to narrow results but the sort is performed without index which can be very slow and even raise errors

Comment: @Philipp sry my bad, what i mean is "field".. still influenced by relational database term :(

Comment: @Sebastian yup! the index is really useful for count() too.. counting result without index is very very slow..